# Is it possible to list values from a data frame that failed to merge?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am successfully merging two dataframes but I also want to see those values that failed the merge. The purpose is to verify that I have all the right values as a result of the merge. Is is possible to dump them to a list or better yet to another data frame?

In the code example below; 'company_f' fails the merge so, that is the record I need to see.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a12bcde0','b20bcde9'], 'title': ['company_a','company_b']})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'serial_number': ['01a2b345','10ab2030','40ab4060'],'title':['company_a','company_b (123)','company_f']}) 

data2['title'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r"\s\(.*\)",value=r'')

pd.merge(data1, data2, on='title')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy solution with [`numpy.setxor1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setxor1d.html):

```
print (np.setxor1d(data1.title,data2.title))
['company_f']
```

---

I think you can use outer join with parameter `indicator` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.merge(data1, data2, on='title', how='outer', indicator=True)

df1 = df[df._merge == 'both']
print (df1)
         id      title serial_number _merge
0  a12bcde0  company_a      01a2b345   both
1  b20bcde9  company_b      10ab2030   both

print (df1.drop('_merge', axis=1))
         id      title serial_number
0  a12bcde0  company_a      01a2b345
1  b20bcde9  company_b      10ab2030
```

---

```
print (df[df._merge != 'both'])
    id      title serial_number      _merge
2  NaN  company_f      40ab4060  right_only

L = df.ix[df._merge != 'both', 'title'].tolist()
print (L)
['company_f']
```